# How to Get corresponding enumeration text when value is passed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

### How to Get correspoding enumeration text when value is passed?

**I need to get the Enumneration text , while passing the value.**

**Below shown is my enumneration class**

```
 public enum Months
        { 
            January=1,
            February=2,
            March=3,
            April=4,
            May=5,
            June=6,
            July=7,
            August=8,
            September=9,
            October =10,
            November=11,
            December=12
        }
```

On passing 1 ,I should get return value as "**January**", on passing  2 ,then it should return "**February**" and so on..

Comment: Important question: Do you want to localise this for different languages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work

```
Months m= (Months)yourInt;
```

to get string then you can do this

```
m.ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

The same can be done using **GetName** method in **Enum** class. Refer the code below

```
int inputValue=5;

string resultValue =Enum.GetName(typeof(MasterEnum.Months),inputValue);

//the value **resultValue**  will be "**May**"
```